# Variadic class function called with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm updating some of my old (<c++11) c++ projects to use some of the new features introduced and I'm stuck at making my EventHandler class variadic.

The old version looked like this:

```
template < class T >
class EventHandler : public virtual IEventHandler
{
  public:

    virtual void onEvent( const T& event ) = 0;

    std::type_index getEventType()
    {
        return std::type_index( typeid( T ) );
    }

    void dispatch( const EventSP &spEv )
    {
        const T* pEv( dynamic_cast< const T* >( spEv.get() ) );

        if( pEv != 0 )
        {
            onEvent( *pEv );
        }
    }
};
```

And used like this:

```
class EventConsumer : public event::EventHandler< event::EvA >
{

public:

    EventConsumer( event::IEventService* pEventService )
    : m_pEventService( pEventService )
    {
        pEventService->addEventHandler( this );
    }

    ~EventConsumer()
    {
        m_pEventService->removeEventHandler( this );
    }

    void onEvent( const event::EvA& event )
    {
        event.printMe();
    }

private:

    event::IEventService* m_pEventService;
};
```

And events declared like this:

```
namespace event {

class EvA : public Event
{
public:
    EvA()
    {
    }

    void printMe() const
    {
        ::std::cout << "Event A" << ::std::endl;
    }
};

class EvB : public Event
{
public:
    EvB()
    {
    }

    void printMe() const
    {
        ::std::cout << "Event B" << ::std::endl;
    }
};

}
```

And now my plan is to make EventHandler variadic to support more than one event but I can't seem to figure out how to write the dispatch function.

I would like to use it like this:

```
class EventConsumer : public event::EventHandler< event::EvA, event::EvB >
{

public:

    EventConsumer( event::IEventService* pEventService )
    : m_pEventService( pEventService )
    {
        pEventService->addEventHandler( this );
    }

    ~EventConsumer()
    {
        m_pEventService->removeEventHandler( this );
    }

    void onEvent( const event::EvA& event )
    {
        event.printMe();
    }

    void onEvent( const event::EvB& event )
    {
        event.printMe();
    }

private:

    event::IEventService* m_pEventService;
};
```

This is what I got so far:

```
template <typename T>
class t_impl
{
public:
    virtual void onEvent( const T& event ) = 0;
};

template < class... Ts >
class EventHandler : public t_impl<Ts>..., public IEventHandler
{
  public:

    EventHandler()
    {
        m_types = { typeid( Ts ) ... };
    }

    using t_impl<Ts>::onEvent...;

    std::list<std::type_index> getEventTypes()
    {
        return m_types;
    }
    
private:
    std::list<std::type_index> m_types;

};
```

I'm guaranteed that the call to `dispatch( const EventSP &spEv )` is called with a shared_ptr with a pointer to one of the types that EventHandler is templated with.

It's dispatch responsibility to call the onEvent function.

Any ideas on how to write the dispatch function?

Thanks,
Linus

Comment: You inherit from `public t_impl<Ts>...` and they are all abstract. Don't you want to inherit from concrete types instead?

Comment: I want to inherit onEvent as pure virtual so I'm forced to implement them in my concrete handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fold expression:

```
void dispatch( const std::shared_ptr<Event> &spEv ) {
    (((std::dynamic_pointer_cast< const Ts >( spEv ) != nullptr) && (onEvent( *std::dynamic_pointer_cast< Ts >( spEv ) ), true))
    || ...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cP7W7qMex)

You can do the same with variadic templates and recursion (taking one `T` at a time from `Ts`), but it requires much more code. This fold expression might not be the cleanest, but it's concise. It basically creates a series of ifs with the `nullptr` check for each `T` in `Ts`, and for the first one that passes, it executes the rest (what is after the `&&`).

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :). Great with your added explanation of the fold expression, appreciate it!